# System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image does not contain a definition for Save? Saving image

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, save

I have a C# web application and have an image that is produce from a byte array.

```
byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(b64);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0,
              imageBytes.Length);
            ImageStudent.ImageUrl = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + b64;
```

This display the image perfectly in the web application. However I would like to save this image to a folder within the project. I have tried this code:

```
String FilePath;
            FilePath = Server.MapPath("~/Images/test2.jpg");
            ImageStudent.Save(FilePath, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

However I get the error:

```
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image does not contain a definition for Save
```

All the .dlls I use I need for other function on the webapplication, is there another method to save this image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[System.Drawing.Image](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9t4syfhh(v=vs.110).aspx) is the namespace you're looking for.

```
System.Drawing.Bitmap b = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(Server.MapPath("~/Images/test2.jpg"));
b.Save(saveFilePath , System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Comment: Thank all is working, I was using System.Drawing.Imaging; Cheers Jeremy

Comment: If you think it could be a namespace clash (ambiguity) simply fully qualify it with `System.Drawing....`

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to take the byte array and save it wherever you want.  A basic sample is this:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\CopyofImage.jpg", imageByte);
```

You cannot make up new methods for existing libraries (like Save on Image class) unless you extend them yourself.